# AWS application source bundle deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am deploying multiple web applications to a single elastic beanstalk tomcat instance using application source bundle. I have two applications app1, app2 in the tomcat. Now I want to make some  changes to app2 and redeploy only app2 and not touch app1, how do I do that?

If I deploy again with source bundle with only app2, app1 is getting deleted.

My aim is to have multiple web apps in the same tomcat with the ability to update only the required web apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to redeploy everything. If you want control over deployment for an individual service then you might want to separate them into two different elastic beanstalk applications.

This was an annoying limitation and one of the reasons my employer moved away from elastic beanstalk.

Comment: Thank you maxm. This is indeed such a road block. If you don't mind me asking what did you end up using? Just curious to know if you are still with aws.

Comment: Hey ascam, please accept and upvote the answer if it's satisfactory :). We moved to kubernetes. I think elastic beanstalk is still great, but every service you run should be a separate elastic beanstalk application. My memory is fuzzy, but I think that comes with some annoyances. My experience with app engine on google cloud was far superior. AWS's new k8s stuff is great though, big fan.

Comment: Ah yes, I think they give you a per-appliction datbase? And some other helpers? Better to manage the db yourself, that coupling was problematic. I think that was it

Comment: Thanks maxm. Appreciate your inputs, We are still exploring which way to go for our application. Thanks